# Регулярное выражение дает не ожидаемый результат

Tags: регулярные-выражения

По задумке регулярное выражение /[\s][\wА-Яа-яЁё]{1,2}[\s]/gm должно находить одно или два символа, обрамленных пробелом или переводом строки. Но в результате в выборку попадает не все. Буду благодарен за помощь!

https://regex101.com/r/Ic0hVy/1

Comment: `\s[\wА-Яа-яЁё]{1,2}(?!\S)` или `(?<!\S)[\wА-Яа-яЁё]{1,2}(?!\S)`

Answer (score 1):

У вас в тексте есть совпадения, которые идут один за другим. Первый пробельный символ каждого последующего совпадения находится с помощью последнего `\s`.

Вам нужно использовать проверку на наличие символа, блок предварительного просмотра:

```
\s[\wА-Яа-яЁё]{1,2}(?!\S)
```

или

```
(?<!\S)[\wА-Яа-яЁё]{1,2}(?!\S)
```

См. [этот пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/rHP7Nx/1) или [этот](https://regex101.com/r/rHP7Nx/2).

`(?!\S)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, требует наличия пробельного символа или конца строки сразу после текущей позиции. `(?<!\S)`  - блок предварительного просмотра назад, требует наличия пробельного символа или начала строки сразу после текущей позиции (пока не поддерживается в FireFox и IE/Edge).